# Enable HTTP DELETE requests on Apache server

Tags: apache-2.2, http

I need to configure my server to permit the http delete method.  currently, I get the following error when I attempt to make this call:

---

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Date: Mon, 11 Apr 2011 20:56:23 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.17 (Win32) PHP/5.3.5
Allow: GET,HEAD,POST,OPTIONS,TRACE
Content-Length: 233
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=98
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

---

I have searched far and wide and have not been able to come up with an answer as to how I can configure the server to allow this request.  Someone please help as it has put a stop to my project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to enable the [WebDAV](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dav.html) module in apache

Comment: any suggestions on how to enable that module?  I cannot find the apache source on my system (I'm running Ubuntu server 10.04, and installed apache through apt-get) so I cannot compile the module in, and I can't figure out the appropriate arguments to LoadModule to get it to load at runtime.

Comment: i also need to know how to do it for windows xp sp3 running WAMP

Comment: I believe I have enabled webdav on windows (using wamp) by following the instructions at http://scalar.wordpress.com/2008/04/13/webdav-on-wamp/ but I still cannot run a DELETE.  I get the same error.